# Python able to handle timestamps timezone-insensitively except in GMT?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to write a function that accepts a UTC timestamp (seconds since epoch) and emits a timezone-aware datetime for that timestamp with tz=utc. But I've encountered a strange issue.

Steps to reproduce:

(a) Set your system timezone to anything not-GMT. (In this case, Los Angeles. Also tested with various Russian, Chinese, South American and Icelandic timezones both before and after GMT+0000).

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from dateutil import tz
>>> epoch_seconds = 0
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_seconds)
>>> print(dt)
1969-12-31 16:00:00
>>> dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=tz.tzlocal())
>>> print(dt)
1969-12-31 16:00:00-08:00
>>> dt = dt.astimezone(tz=tz.tzutc())
>>> print(dt)
1970-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
>>> assert '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z}'.format(dt) == '1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000'
>>>
```

(b) Set your timezone to London/Dublin/something equivalent to GMT.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from dateutil import tz
>>> epoch_seconds = 0
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_seconds)
>>> print(dt)
1970-01-01 01:00:00
>>> dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=tz.tzlocal())
>>> print(dt)
1970-01-01 01:00:00+00:00
>>> dt = dt.astimezone(tz=tz.tzutc())
>>> print(dt)
1970-01-01 01:00:00+00:00
>>> assert '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z}'.format(dt) == '1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
>>>
```

Can you help me understand why this seemingly works in any non-GMT timezone but not in GMT?

The intent of the code is:

1. Create a datetime using 0 seconds since epoch: `dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)`
2. Tell that datetime what timezone it is currently in: `dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=tz.tzlocal())`
3. "Move" it from the local timezone to UTC: `dt = dt.astimezone(tz=tz.tzutc())`

I think the problem lies in `dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)` because even at that point calling `print(dt)` shows 01:00 as the time instead of 00:00.

**Update** It gives 1am because the UK was actually in "British Standard Time" (GMT+0100) on 1st January 1970. Maybe dateutil's tz doesn't know that? It's just an abstract representation of the *current* rules? Maybe?

Comment: This is with python 3.5.2 if that's relevant.

Comment: It depends on **which** day you ran the program... Europe/London != GMT; London switched from DST to standard time last night...

Comment: I ran it today. I'm trying to write code that doesn't care what timezone it is run in or whether daylight savings is active. I want to give a UTC timestamp to a function and have it return a UTC datetime representing that same timestamp. I don't want the current date/day/timezone or anything else to have any influence on the result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you happen to run it **exactly** today. UK changed summer time exactly today. Iceland *doesn't* observe DST. Russia neither. NZ didn't change today.

Comment: How funny! Do you know how I can write a routine that works on every day of the year in any timezone that takes UTC timestamp seconds as input and produces a datetime with tz=UTC of that same time? Thanks!

Comment: I found the cause here of 0 giving 1am, but not the fix: "A further inquiry during 1966–67 led the government of Harold Wilson to introduce the British Standard Time experiment, with Britain remaining on GMT+1 throughout the year. This took place between 27 October 1968 and 31 October 1971, when there was a reversion to the previous arrangement." (Wikipedia articles on British Summer Time.)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this using the `pytz` library. I don't think it can be solved using `datetime` because `datetime`'s timezone conversion doesn't know that the British used GMT+0100 for the entire of 1970 and not just for summer time.

With system timezone set to Europe/London:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> epoch_seconds = 0
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch_seconds)
>>> print(dt)
1970-01-01 00:00:00
>>> dt = timezone('UTC').localize(dt)
>>> print(dt)
1970-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
>>> assert '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z}'.format(dt) == '1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000'
```

With system timezone set to America/Los_Angeles

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> epoch_seconds = 0
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch_seconds)
>>> print(dt)
1970-01-01 00:00:00
>>> dt = timezone('UTC').localize(dt)
>>> print(dt)
1970-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
>>> assert '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z}'.format(dt) == '1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000'
>>>
```

Local time never has to come into it this way - you can just generate a naïve timestamp, tell it to be UTC with pytz's `localize`.

Comment: Still curious if there's a solution that doesn't use a library but happy to have it working!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to write a function that accepts a UTC timestamp (seconds since epoch) and emits a timezone-aware datetime for that timestamp with tz=utc

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime, timezone

aware_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_seconds, timezone.utc)
```

> I don't think it can be solved using datetime because datetime's timezone conversion doesn't know that the British used GMT+0100 for the entire of 1970 and not just for summer time.

If python has access to the tz database on your system then it does know the rules:

```
$ TZ=Europe/London ptpython
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> epoch_seconds = 0
>>> aware_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_seconds, timezone.utc) 
>>> aware_dt
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> aware_dt.astimezone() # local time (1am)
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 1, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), 'BST'))
>>> _.astimezone(timezone.utc) # back to utc
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

To provide a portable access to the tz database, you could use `pytz` timezone e.g., via `tzlocal` module:

```
>>> import tzlocal # $ pip install tzlocal
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_seconds, tzlocal.get_localzone())  # local time (1am)
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 1, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/London' BST+1:00:00 STD>)
```

btw, `dateutil` provides access to the tz database too. If it doesn't work: it is either the wrong usage or a bug. Try to update to the latest `python-dateutil` version, to see whether the issue disappears.